# Symlinking WordPress WP-ADMIN and WP-INCLUDES

Tags: wp-admin

Is it possible to symlink wp-admin and wp-includes located in another directory?

I found this tutorial http://www.htmlgraphic.com/symlinking-wordpress-core-files-wordpress-skeleton/

but that one symlinking whole WordPress install.

What I need is only wp-admin and wp-includes, so I can still maintain wp-content for each of my sites separately.

I haven't try it yet myself. Since if it's possible I will do that on production.

Comment: Note that you can put WP Core in a subfolder on its own, and keep your wp-contents folder and wp-config.php outside of it. Symlinking shouldn't be necessary, using multisite may be a better solution too

Comment: Multisite is not an option right now, since all of the sites have been working on it's own from the beginning and the data are all huge, so migrating to multisite will be a tough and time consuming job for each of the site.

Comment: If I were to put WP Core in a subfolder can this be shared to the other sites?

Comment: You'd need to write an index.php that loaded the WP Core file, and set the path of the content directory, there's no reason multiple files can't load from the same folder for different sites

Answer (score 1):

In general it is possible to symlink `wp_includes` but not `wp-admin`. The main difference is that various places in admin want to know the path and they calculate it relative to the file which was first invoke to handle the admin request. The problem is that for symlinks PHP returns the path to the actual file and not its virtual path, making it impossible to find the resources (plugina, themes, whatever) of the specific wordpress install.

As implied from the first part, I did try to do it, but right now I don't see the value of attempting that. With the improvements in PHP parsing you just get less value from improving memory/cpu by parsing one file instead of 5, and this setting goes against the philosophy of separating unrelated resources to help localize potential problem, as a failed upgrade in site A can just bring down all your sites.